# Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I want to test if two samples are drawn from the same distribution.
I generated two random arrays and used a python function to derive the KS statistic $D$ and the two-tailed p-value $P$:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> a=np.random.random_integers(1,9,4)
>>> a
array([3, 7, 4, 3])
>>> b=np.random.random_integers(1,9,5)
>>> b
array([2, 2, 3, 7, 9])
>>> stats.ks_2samp(a,b)
(0.40000000000000002, 0.75428850089034016)
```

From the documentation of http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html I know that

$$D=0.40000000000000002$$
and
$$P=0.75428850089034016$$
So the probability that the two samples are drawn from the same distribution is $\sim75\%$.

Now my question is what does $D$ tell me? And is there a simple way to calculate these two values by hand?

The wikipedia article does not have a simple example with two samples, that is why I am trying finally to find an answer here.

Comment: The p-value of 0.75 can not be interpreted as you have put it. What it says is, that if the populations the samples were drawn from are indeed identical, then the probability of getting a result as extreme or more extreme than you observed is 0.75  The conclusion is said like this: we fail to reject the hypothesis that the samples came from the same population distribution.

Comment: ok, so this is compatible that random samples (which I generated here) do not have a common distribution?

And if the p-value would be $\sim10^{-6}$, then the two samples must have different distributions? What is the significant value, at which fail or not fail is decided?

And what is the D-value?

Comment: it seems that (even large) random samples have the same distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One rejects the null hypothesis when the P-value is small. 
A common criterion is to reject if the P-values is less than 0.05.

In a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, the D-statistic measures the maximum
diagonal distance between the empirical cumulative distribution
functions (ECDFs) of the two samples. (Everything is re-scaled
so the ECDF fits inside the unit square.)

An ECDF is made by sorting the data and plotting it along the
horizontal axis. Then the ECDF is a non-decreasing stair-step function that rises by 1/n at each of the n sorted data points.
An ECDF is intended to approximate the cumulative distribution
function (CDF) of the probability distribution from which
the data were randomly sampled.

It is often difficult to distinguish between two distributions
with small amounts of data. So it might be more revealing if
you generated your fake experimental data with larger sample
sizes.

Below is a session in R, in which x and y come from the
same distribution and z comes from a different distribution.
I show K-S tests to compare x and y and to compare x and z.

```
 x = rnorm(100, 50, 2);  y = rnorm(100, 50, 2);  z = rnorm(100, 65, 3)
 ks.test(x,y)

 #        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

 # data:  x and y 
 # D = 0.11, p-value = 0.5806  # Huge P-value, don't reject
 # alternative hypothesis: two.sided 

 ks.test(x,z)

 #        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

 # data:  x and z 
 # D = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16  # tiny P-value, so reject
 # alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```