# How to group similarity samples?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have different samples, some from the same distribution. Let's say I have 6 samples, $S_1$ to $S_6$, where $\{S_1,S_2,S_3\}$, $\{S_4,S_5\}$,$\{S_6\}$ are groups of samples from the same distribution. What method can I use to group samples as above?

I know I can use Kolmogorov-Smirnov two sample test, so my main idea is to compare any two possible combinations and group those with a similarity higher than a certain threshold (lets say $0.8$).

Pseudo code:

```
for X=S1:S6
    for Y=S1:S6 and Y!=X:
        stats.ks_2samp(X,Y)
        if p>0.8:
            group(X,Y)
```

Question 1: As I read in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251401/kolmogorov-smirnov-two-sample-test#comment2543944_1251401), it seems like the $p$-value does not show the probability that two samples come from the same distribution. Is this true?

Question 2: Given $n_1$ and $n_2$ as samples sizes, can this formula be useful, i.e.
$$\frac{n_1n_2}{n1 + n2}\ge4\,?$$

> The asymptotic $p$-value becomes very accurate for large sample sizes,
> and is believed to be reasonably accurate for sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$,
> such that
> $$\frac{n_1n_2}{n1 + n2}\ge4.$$

source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop#outputarg_p

Question 3: Is there another way to perform this task?

---

**Update** from this [source](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?interpreting_results_kolmogorov-smirnov_test.htm)

> The $p$-value is the answer to this question:
>
> If the two samples were randomly sampled from identical populations,
> what is the probability that the two cumulative frequency
> distributions would be as far apart as observed? More precisely, what
> is the chance that the value of the Komogorov-Smirnov $D$-statistic
> would be as large or larger than observed?

The above statement is in contrast with [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251401/kolmogorov-smirnov-two-sample-test#comment2543944_1251401) I mentioned above, so I suppose the statement in comment was wrong.

Comment: i asked my question with 3 sub-quesitons. If it is too much,let me know so I remove 2 of them.

Comment: I update the question with some new info